# Formula for the current row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row

I want to create a formula that allows me to select the data for column E and the row I am currently on (eg 64). Is there a formula for the current row I am on so I can copy and paste it? I want to data to go into various columns so I can't just extend out the formula.

Thanks!

Harry

Comment: Maybe `=$E:$E` ( returns value from the row the formula is on by virtue of Implicit Intersection)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, be more specific. You want to copy the value of Active Cell in Column E to somewhere else or what? Why the normal copy/paste does not fit for you?

Comment: Thanks Chris Neilsen- this worked perfectly- but for some reason I can't +1 your response (new to this forum...)

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for R1C1 reference style (Options > Formulas > Working with formulas).