# VBA Excel formula for current row instead of lastrow

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I found a similar query here:

[Formula for the current row in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537715/formula-for-the-current-row-in-excel)

but with no reasonable answer.

My query is related to the situation here:

[VBA Excel autofill the table based on userform, when data comes from the other sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285689/vba-excel-autofill-the-table-based-on-userform-when-data-comes-from-the-other-s)

I am trying to manage the code.

```
 lastrowG = wks.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 LastrowH = wks.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowL = wks.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 LastrowAD = wkf.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'LastrowAE = Sheets("Formulas").Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 wkf.Range("AD" & LastrowAD).value = ("=IF(Tracker!L" & lastrowL & "<20,'1:00','2:00'")
 wkf.Range("AE" & LastrowAE).value = ("=Formulas!AD" & LastrowAD)
 wks.Range("H" & LastrowH).value = ("=G" & lastrowG & "+Formulas!AE" & LastrowAE)
```

I was trying to manage with this solution, but the problem is that the code always brings me the last row.

In my situation when I have the formula in the AD column populated down to the AD370 or something.
In the AE formula, I would like to have an auto-population based on the value from the AD column in the same row.
It's like AE10 = Value (=AD10).

In this code, which I have I am getting the last value, as you can see in the image above.
How can I get the value from exactly the same row?

**UPDATE:**

According to this solution

https://excel.tips.net/T002267_Selecting_a_Cell_in_the_Current_Row.html

I tried to do sth like this

```
     LastrowAD = wkf.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).ActiveCell.Row + 1
```

But now I am getting error:

**The object doesn't support this property or method**

[image]

Comment: If understand what you need correctly, this should work: `wkf.Range("AE" & LastrowAE).value = ("=Formulas!AD" & LastrowAE)` since you are placing into the next available row in AE and you want it to match the same in `Formulas!AD`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to step through the AD column and add them one at a time. The below For loop should do the trick.

```
Dim LastrowAD as Long
Dim rowAD as Range
Dim wkf as Worksheet
Dim i as Variant

Set wkf = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulas")

LastrowAD = wkf.Cells(Rows.count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
Set rowAD = wkf.range("AD2:AD" & LastrowAD)

'puts formula from AD row x into AE row x
for each i in rowAD
    wkf.Cells(i.row, "AE").Formula = "=Formulas!AD" & i.row
next i

'rest of code
end sub
```